# QGIS Map to Autocad (not SVG,PDF OR Image)

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3, export, autocad

Is there any way to export the map extent set with Altas points in QGIS to convert to DWG instead of whole project or any shapefile?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the site. If you don't already have one, you will first want to create a vector layer that matches the extent of your largest map layer.

You can right click the new layer in the table of contents then and go to "Save as" then save as Autocad .dxf file.

Depending on the type of CRS you are using (i.e. projected or geographic) you may need to change the geographic coordinate system option.

Comment: will that export have thee data I have in map as well as layout I made?

Answer (score -1):

You can see in this video the alternative to insert maps in AutoCAD in georeferenced image format from QGIS.

https://youtu.be/djTXvYMfA0U